# Can't unlock the screen on Nexus 4

Tags: lock-screens, nexus-4, locked-out

I got a new Nexus 4 yesterday. It works fine on WiFi.

When I turn it on this morning, I can't get past the screen lock. It won't allow me to get into the device. It just shows the time and phone keyboard. It tells me that I can only make emergency calls.

I have not installed a SIM card yet. Would doing so fix the problem?

Comment: What is your security method? Is it just slide or patten or pin or password etc? I have a guess that you might have enabled pin or password as security option.

Comment: By turn on do you mean physically turn the device on or just wake from sleep? It could be that the system has frozen up, and taking out the battery and putting it back in, and then turning the phone on again, might fix things. This has certainly happened to me before with tablets. **Edit:** No, there shouldn't be any reason why not having a SIM card in would stop the device from unlocking (to my knowledge, at least).